# Orientatin issue in ios 6.0 and later

Tags: iphone, ios6, uiinterfaceorientation

I am developing one application, in which there are number of UIViews inside one UIViewController. Now the issues is that it is having all the UIViews in the Landscape mode, here only one UIView is in portrait. I am not able to get this particular output using shouldAutorotate method.

Can anybody suggest me specific way to short out this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@pratik-bhiyani Thanks...
But I have already done this kind of code to get the specific code when I need to rotate my view

```
- (IBAction)btnClickToRedeem:(id)sender
{
    isPortraitRqurd = TRUE;
    [self shouldAutorotate];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    if(isPortraitRqurd)
        return (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
    else
        return (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);

}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if(isPortraitRqurd)
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    else
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    if(isPortraitRqurd)
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
        isPortraitRqurd = FALSE;
    }

    else
        return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}
```

Comment: are you made change in build setting ?

Comment: Yes I have done it then also not able to set portrait view from Landscape.

Comment: return YES; and in build setting(as shown in image) press UpsideDown button also and make it dark.

Comment: aceept and upvote if you find my answer useful , have a nice day :)